# Is it ok to copy&paste a comment linking to another meta discussion more than once?

Tags: support, per-site-meta, cross-posting

At [gaming meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com) there are three questions whether mapping and modding questions should be part of the site, and since a suggestion was sending these to [gamedev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com) I started a discussion there. Is it ok to comment on each of the three questions with the same:

> If gaming won't welcome these questions, maybe [gamedev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com) will? I started a discussion there, [Do mod- and map-making questions belong here?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58/do-mod-and-map-making-questions-belong-here).

Meta doesn't provide rep, so I hope my intention of helping those to sites to cooperate without unnecessary overlap is clear, yet I think copy&pasting might be frowned upon...

Comment: Even though I asked one of those questions - if they are duplicates two out of the three should be marked for closure. However, my question asks about downloading/installing mods, and the other talks about development of mods so they're not duplicates.

Comment: @ChrisF: I didn't intend to flag any question as dupe, I only wanted to know whether copy&pasting the link to the gamedev meta is ok

Comment: If the same comment applies to more than one question/answer then I can't see a problem. I do it all the time with off topic questions.

Comment: @ChrisF I don't consider them duplicates. Your question is about actual information on mods. The ones Oak posted are about the development of mods (which is an entirely different beast) and the usage of map editors (which is just different completely). The latter two are the ones I would point to Game Dev. Yours, not so much.

Comment: @Grace - the point I was making was that if the same comment applied to several questions then they were *potentially* duplicates. However, checking the questions referred to I realised they weren't. Sorry for any confusion caused.

Comment: @ChrisF No worries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as a comment makes sense in the thread, it doesn't matter whether it's posted on other questions.

Copy-pasting a comment is particularly helpful in dealing with off-topic posts, in the LQRQ there are even generic auto-comments, and [there's a script that'll let you create your own](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se).

(this answer is partially copied from [ChrisF's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57632/is-it-ok-to-copypaste-a-comment-linking-to-another-meta-discussion-more-than-on/236773#comment136411_57632))